# What relevant information can be extracted out of an Image?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, photo, data-science

What all info can be derived out of an image?
-gps data
-tags
-time taken

I am trying to do some data engineering and just wondering what all information I can extract out of an image? Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Try running `jhead -v SomeImage.jpg` and/or `exiftool SomeImage.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the file format.

Some image file formats specify means for storing meta data.

There is no guarantee that this meta data fields are actually used so even if the file format provides meta data the file may contain no useful meta information.

Answer (score 1):

For most image formats, width, height and pixel depth, full stop. Sometimes physical pixel size, though you can doubt the "updatedness".

Tiff and Jpeg have provisions to include innumerable information tags, most of which are optional and some of which can be user-defined (and of course will be unsupported by existing readers).

Image tags are a jungle and are just ignored by most users/implementors. There is no standardization, because there is no need, and any attempt to be "complete" ends-up in ridiculous enumerations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#Example